# How do I remove missing migrations from project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-migrations

So I have made the foolish error of manually removing migration files from my project.

They still show up in `db:migrate:status`, but I'm not able to `rollback` or `destroy` them without creating new empty files with MigrationID_somename, and then running destroy on those placeholder files.

Is there a better way to forget missing migration files?

```
me$ rake db:migrate:status

database: [...]/db/development.sqlite3

 Status   Migration ID    Migration Name
--------------------------------------------------
   up     20141203044050  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20141203044501  ********** NO FILE **********

me$ rake db:migrate:down VERSION=20141203044501
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::UnknownMigrationVersionError: 

No migration with version number 20141203044501

/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:932:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:818:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:79:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate:down
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could probably just use a database client and delete the rows from the schema_migrations table (if you promise never to do it again ;).

Comment: I've sadly had to do this before.

Comment: The SQL line would be `delete from schema_migrations where version = '20141203044501';`